# How to customize rules on Fiddler Alpha on Mono (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, mono, fiddler

Please note: I am working on Mac OS and I am trying to get this to work on the Alpha on Mono version of Fiddler.

More specifically, I want to edit the `OnBeforeRequest` function in CustomRules.js, so that I can redirect traffic to a development box for testing. Just using the AutoResponder rules is not sufficient.

I've successfully been able to get this to work on Windows. On the Windows build, we can do:

Rules -> Customize Rules (Ctrl+R)

After installing the Alpha Fiddler on my Mac, there's a Fiddler directory with an empty Scripts subdirectory, no SampleRules.js to be found.

I've spent a long time on this and am wondering if it's just a good idea to try finding another way/tool.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which build of Fiddler for Mono did you install specifically? Version 4.4.5.0 did not include a scripting engine. The later version 4.4.8.4 introduced a new scripting engine (based on C# because JScript.Net is not available on Mono).

I haven't built an OSX installer for the later build yet, but you should be able to just unzip the archive.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I installed 4.4.5.0. I also tried installing the 4.4.8.4 Linux build and unzipped it but I can't run the .exe file because it's a Windows application. Is there another way to get the 4.4.8.4 version to run on Mac that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The EXE File isn't a Windows application, it's a Mono program. You run it via `mono Fiddler.exe` from a terminal window.

Comment: I just tried it and it hangs while "Loading Scripting..." as it's opening. I see this was a known issue on Mac (http://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-mac-hangs). Is this still an ongoing problem and is there no updates on how to handle it? I've tried force quitting etc and it still hangs. Thank you for all the quick responses!

Comment: If it helps, I also see a FiddlerScript Compiler error: Unexpected symbol 'import' Line:1.

Comment: The compiler error you're mentioning would only appear if your CustomRules file contains JScript.NET code instead of the (Expected-for-Mono) C#.

Comment: After deleting the previous Fiddler I downloaded (the Mac build), the Linux version opened successfully. Thank you!